# show random number < 0.8 not working properly

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm kinda new on JS so I tried to do this, I made this to test the random function and I want to show only random numbers below 0.8, but sometimes it shows above 0.8 also more than one time in a row, how do I fix it ?
This is my first post ever here, so sorry if I did something wrong.
Thanks. :)

```js
function rn() {
    var a = Math.random()
    return a
}

function writerandon() {
    var x = 0

    while (x < 100) {
        if (rn() < 0.8) {
            document.write(rn() + "<br>")
        }

        if (rn() > 0.8) {
            x = 100
        }

        x++
    }
}
//
document.getElementById("11").innerHTML = writerandon()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>exp</title>
</head>

<body id="bd">   

<h1 id="11"></h1>

</body>

<script src="exp.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have a wrapper function around a single function call? That's counter-productive and obscures what you're actually doing.

Comment: Idk i was just testing, im new on JS, now that you sayd, it makes sense, also, Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being new and learning. That's what we're all here for.

Answer (score 6):

Your code makes *two* random number calls, each of which may have a different value. The fix is to use `else` to ensure only one branch fires:

```
    let n = Math.random();
    if (n < 0.8) {
        document.write(n + "<br>")
    }
    else {
        x = 100
    }
```

Just because you've wrapped `Math.random()` in a function doesn't mean it fires only once. *Each and every call to `rn()` will return a new value*. The local variable `a` is initialized anew with each function call. It *does not* persist between calls.

In your original code around 16% of the time (80% x 20%) you'd fluke out and trigger both branches.

Comment: Also I think `document.write()` is not called for here.

Comment: @Pointy Wow, another call. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `document.getElementById("11").innerHTML = writerandon()` won't that simply put `undefined` into the h1? I don't see `writerandon` do any explicit return.

Comment: @connexo Probably, but that's a whole other problem.

Comment: Thanks, yall answers where great,  now i understand why wasnt working, also im quite impressed how this comunity works, it was really fast. ps. i started learning JS some days ago. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assign the return value to a variable in order to hold the same value over different conditions.

```js
function rn() {
    var a = Math.random()
    return a
}

function writerandon() {
    var x = 0

    while (x < 100) {
        const randomNumber = rn();

        if (randomNumber < 0.8) {
            document.write(randomNumber + "<br>")
        }

        if (randomNumber > 0.8) {
            x = 100
        }

        x++
    }
}
//
document.getElementById("11").innerHTML = writerandon()
```

Comment: Thanks, yall answers where great,  now i understand why wasnt working, also im quite impressed how this comunity works, it was really fast. ps. i started learning JS some days ago. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling `rn()` multiple, and it returns different numbers each time. The result you test in `if` is not the same one that you display with `document.write()`, or the one that you test in the second `if`.

You need to save the number to a variable so you can test and display the same number.

Also, use `else` when you want to do something when the previous test failed.

```js
function rn() {
  var a = Math.random()
  return a
}

function writerandon() {
  var x = 0

  while (x < 100) {
    var num = rn();
    if (num < 0.8) {
      document.getElementById("bd").innerHTML += (num + "<br>")
    } else {
      break;
    }

    x++
  }
}
//
document.getElementById("11").innerHTML = writerandon()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>exp</title>
</head>

<body id="bd">

  <h1 id="11"></h1>

</body>

<script src="exp.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, yall answers where great,  now i understand why wasnt working, also im quite impressed how this comunity works, it was really fast. ps. i started learning JS some days ago. :)